# error datetime picker converting

Tags: c#, datetimepicker

here is my error 
[image]

even i tried: `dtp_ngaycap.Value` it still confirms me that error.
here is the code of `CNcommands` class

```
   public bool CNcommands(string commandType,string tenchunha,string nguoidaidien, string chucvu, int soCMDN, DateTime ngaycap, string diachi, string masothue, string nguoithuhuong, string sotaikhoan,string nganhang,string sodienthoai, string diachiemail, string diachinganhang, int maCN)
    {
        if (commandType == "insert")
        {
            string insertCN = "INSERT INTO [QLThueNha].[dbo].[ChuNha][MaChuNha],[TenChuNha],[Nguoidaidien],[Chucvu],[SoCMND],[Ngaycap],[Diachi],[Masothue],[Nguoithuhuong],[Sotaikhoan],[Nganhang],[Sodienthoai],[DiachimailCN],[Diachinganhang])VALUES('" + tenchunha + "','" + nguoidaidien + "','" + chucvu + "','" + soCMDN + "','" + ngaycap + "','" + diachi + "','" + masothue + "','" + nguoithuhuong + "','" + sotaikhoan + "','" + nganhang + "','" + sodienthoai + "','" + diachiemail + "','" + diachinganhang + "')";
            if (executeQuery(insertCN, ref rowAffect_) == true && rowAffect_ == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else if (commandType == "update")
        {
            string updateCN = "UPDATE [QLThueNha].[dbo].[ChuNha]  SET [TenChuNha] = '" + tenchunha + "',[Nguoidaidien] = '" + nguoidaidien + "',[Chucvu] = '" + chucvu + "',[SoCMND] = '" + soCMDN + "',[Ngaycap] = '" + ngaycap + "',[Diachi] = '" + diachi + "',[Masothue] = '" + masothue + "',[Nguoithuhuong] = '" + nguoithuhuong + "',[Sotaikhoan] = '" + sotaikhoan + "',[Nganhang] = '" + nganhang + "',[Sodienthoai] = '" + sodienthoai + "',[DiachimailCN] = '" + diachiemail + "',[Diachinganhang] = '" + diachinganhang + "' WHERE <Search Conditions,,>";
            if (executeQuery(updateCN, ref rowAffect_) == true && rowAffect_ == 1)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
        //if (commandType == "delete")
        //{
        //    string deleteCN = "SET [TenChuNha] = '" + tenchunha + "',[Nguoidaidien] = '" + nguoidaidien + "',[Chucvu] = '" + chucvu + "',[SoCMND] = '" + soCMDN + "',[Ngaycap] = '" + ngaycap + "',[Diachi] = '" + diachi + "',[Masothue] = '" + masothue + "',[Nguoithuhuong] = '" + nguoithuhuong + "',[Sotaikhoan] = '" + sotaikhoan + "',[Nganhang] = '" + nganhang + "',[Sodienthoai] = '" + sodienthoai + "',[DiachimailCN] = '" + diachiemail + "',[Diachinganhang] = '" + diachinganhang + "' WHERE <Search Conditions,,>";
        //    if (executeQuery(deleteCN, ref rowAffect_) == true && rowAffect_ == 1)
        //    {
        //        return true;
        //    }
        //}

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FormatException` is thrown because of the last parameter you pass to the `CNcommands` method:

```
int.Parse("");
```

Check also the `Convert.ToDateTime("");`//note if you are using `DateTimePicker` then no need to parse to `Convert.ToDateTime` because the `dateTimePicker.Value` is `DateTime`.

And also check `int.Parse(txt_sosmdn.Text)`

However you should also consider re-factoring your method.

Comment: no, i tried to replace 'int.Parce("")' by 1, but it still firms me that error

Comment: then check the Convert.ToDateTime(/*data*/) however if you are using DateTimePicker then you should not convert.

Comment: @Son: check also `int.Parse(txt_sosmdn.Text)`

Comment: yeah, you are right. 'int.Parse(txt_sosmdn.Text)' is the main problem, i forgot to check null value at this field text, thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are trying to parse an invalid value to int..
int.Parse converts the string representation of number to its 32-bit signed integer equivalent..
And that string must be a valid number so provide a valid number there..

like

```
    int.Parse("0");
```